# Writing array data to a binary file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, binary, save

I'm trying to store the following arrays in binary, and read them back in after:

```
private int[10] number;
private String[10] name;
private int[10] age;
```

What is the best way to store them to a binary file, and read them back in afterwards? An example value for each array are:

```
number[0] = 1; name[0] = "Henry"; age[0] = 35;
```

So the data belongs sort of together.

Edit: Basically I want to store data from variables (arrays) using a binary text file, binary is a must, and then read the data back in. So in short I want to have a way to store data so when I close the application the data is not lost and can be retrieved each session.

Comment: Can you use like key value pairs but values being separated by comma, like below ? 0=1,Henry,35

Comment: Object Serializer? Json? XML? Prob my top 3 in that order.

Comment: It has to be 3 different arrays? Can you store an object?

Comment: @royalGhost maybe, it has to be binary though

Comment: @BernardoRocha yes it has to be 3 different arrays, unless you could combine them in some sort of way as I think you try to suggest by storing an object? I want to use something like a FileWriter or OutputStreamWriter

Answer (score 2):

You could write custom encoder and decoder e.g. by mapping `String` to `byte[]` with `String.getBytes()` and then writing each byte with `OutputStream.write()` method. The question is what do you mean by "the best way" because:

1. Do you need to support different locales? What is the `String` locale as `getBytes()` uses platform's default charset.
2. Do you need to compress the binary data to save space as `String` might be either very long or very short.
3. Do you plan to share the binary files with other applications? If so it's best to use a format supported in few languages e.g. [Google Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf).

If the files are ever to be read outside of your application then Protobuf seems like a sane choice. It would however be an overkill for a Hello World application.

The simpliest approach would be to use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` but it's far from pretty:

```
String fileName = "data.set";

try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
  for (int n : number) {
    out.writeInt(n);
  }
  for (String n : name) {
    out.writeUTF(n);
  }
  for (int a : age) {
    out.writeInt(a);
  }
}

try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
  for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    number[i] = in.readInt();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    name[i] = in.readUTF();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
    age[i] = in.readInt();
  }
}
```

Comment: The binary files won't be shared with other applications. It's just used to save variables to a text file (binary is a must) and read back from them so when I close the application, the data is not lost.

Comment: I'd go with Protobuf if it's not a Hello World application. It's straightforward. Just wrap your data into a type: it looks like you can create `new Person[10]` with `number`, `name` and `age` being `Person` fields. Then create a `.proto` file, generate the Java classes from the `.proto` file and use it as show [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/examples/AddPerson.java#L62).

Alternatively you can use standard Java serialization using `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` but you still need a wrapper class for your data.

Comment: @Walt added an example of Java serialization